# What powers do the thirty coins provide?

Tags: thirty-coins

In *Thirty Coins*, everyone agrees that the thirty silver coins of Judas are extremely powerful, with dark hints that if Hitler and Napoleon only had a few, someone with all of them would be very bad news. However, we do not seem to see many overt cases of someone actually using the coins' powers.

We see that Fabio, who wears at least one coin, can cast all manner of spells by chanting certain words and employing the right materials and gestures, but by all appearances, this is just sorcery that anyone could theoretically learn or cast with or without a coin, as we see Father Vergara do, for instance. "Father Ángel" is capable of even more, but he is a literal demon, and does not use the coins.

Certainly, once Fabio puts on a mitre with all thirty coins, it does little to prevent him from being tackled by Vergara, nor from bleeding profusely and being unconscious or dead after hitting the ground.

So what powers do the thirty coins actually grant?

Comment: We don't know but whatever it is and however great it is, it needs to be unlocked in some way. I always thought of the coins as a huge gun. Sure, a gun is a powerful thing, powerful enough to kill somebody. Yet, it still needs to be assembled, loaded and aimed. And it also won't protect you from being tackled and killed.

Comment: You can buy thirty things that cost one coin, or one thing that costs thirty coins.

Answer (score 1):

As of the end of the second season, the answer is, surprisingly, that it is still somewhat unclear.

- After getting a coin, Mercedes demonstrates telekinetic and other powers. However, these powers are similar to those  displayed by Fabio, which he also seems to have after being brought by as a sort of zombie by Satan, despite lacking a coin, so it seems equally possible that during the interlude, Mercedes simply was trained in sorcery the same way Fabio had been.
- The coins are described at various points as a powerful source of energy, including at one point in the context of the supercomputer that Barbrow used to calculate the numbers needed to activate the Nazca saucer. *However*, when the numbers are calculated, the coins are with Barbrow, so it seems that the supposition that the coins were being used to power the computer was *incorrect*.
- Barbrow also claims that the coins are necessary to protect him and his chosen when they go to another dimension through the Eye of God. *However*, Vergara also goes to this same dimension, without a coin or even a saucer to protect him, so the veracity of this statement also remains unclear.

That said, we have two examples of situations where the power of the coins is displayed explicitly:

- Mercedes was explicitly able to overpower another person due to having more coins than he did, and even force his coins to come to her.
- In order to capture Paco and teleport him to Barbrow's boat, Mercedes removes a coin from Barbrow's box, suggesting that she needed the coin to accomplish this feat.

The general idea seems to be that, more than providing explicit powers, the coins are a sort of power booster. So while anyone can learn sorcery, having a coin makes performing it much easier and allows for more powerful feats with less knowledge—thus why Fabio, without any coins, is easily bested telekinetically by Mercedes, who has one. On the other hand, having a coin without any knowledge of sorcery, as was the case with Elena, provides no benefits. This also explains Mercedes's relatively rapid ascent into the ranks of the magically adept.